# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047 when using sudo to excute Python code

Tags: python, linux, cx-oracle

I am new to Ubunu. I wrote a simple Python code to test Oracle connection on a Ubuntu server. When I use the following command to ru it:

```
$ python3 test_oracle_connection.py
```

The code was executed successfully. But when I tried to use sudo the run the code, like this:

```
$ sudo python3 test_oracle_connect.py
```

I got the following errors:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx_oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help.

I had set the folloing environment variable in ~/.profile

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/insantclient_21_1
```

And I am using Python 3.8.5.

I have been struggling with this for days. Really need your help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run sudo, you are changing to root (a different user) and therefore the environment variable is missing. You have a couple of options to consider:

1. Use global configuration (/etc/ld.so.conf) so that you don't have to set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
2. Create a bash script that sets the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then runs your script. Use the bash script instead of running your script directly.